# scrollToFirstError not working on Select field of the antd Form

Tags: reactjs, forms, validation, scroll, antd

I created Form using ant design components. I've added scrollToFirstError flag, so form is scrolled to the first failed validation. It works when first error is on the InputField, but not when it's on the Select field. It show's the error message and form does not get submitted, as it shouldn't, but the scroll isn't happening. Has anyone faced the similar problem?

I've tried a workaround by using form instance to force scroll onFinishFailed event, but it still didnt work

Comment: Please share a CodePen / CodeSandbox / an example of your implementation so someone else can have a look and help. Scrolling to Select form fields are working for me on v4.24.13

Comment: I am having the same issue

Comment: I solved this by wrapping scroll logic into the setTimeout